# Finding probability of such: P(A intersect B intersect C)

Tags: probability

I got this question wrong and I don't know why
[image]

Find (R∩H∩T)

**My working out:**

(R∩H∩T) = (R) * (H∣R) * (T∣R∩H)

(R) = $\frac{59}{174}$

(H∣R) = $\frac{31}{59}$

(T∣R∩H) = ($\frac{18}{174}$ \ $\frac{31}{174}$) -- Where I think I went wrong

So answer = $\frac{59}{174}$ * $\frac{31}{59}$ * ($\frac{18}{174}$ \ $\frac{31}{174}$)

= $\frac{3}{29}$

**Actual answer:**

= $\frac{13}{174}$

Comment: $P(T|R\cap H)=13/31$, I think.  (The lowermost right cell, divided by the sum of the 2 lower right cells.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Getting the correct answer is a straightforward application of Laplace's rule, you do not need to decompose the problem at all:

$$
P(R \cap H \cap T) = \frac{\text{Cases where }R \cap H \cap T}{\text{Total cases}} = \frac{13}{174}
$$

However, your decomposition is correct. Where you went wrong is indeed where you point out, as by the definition of conditional probability we have that $P(T|R\cap H) = \frac{P(R \cap H \cap T)}{P(H \cap T)} = \frac{13/174}{31/174} = \frac{13}{31} \neq \frac{18}{31}$.

Comment: (+1) for correct fraction, But might have mentioned that conditional probabilities are not needed. OP's initial equation is true, but irrelevant.

Comment: @BruceET agreed, edited for clarity